# How to resize frame after hiding a component in wxwidgets

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I have a frame which has 4 textboxes and one link(change no of textboxes). when user clicks on link I am hiding 4th textbox. but what happens is after hiding 4th textbox, it's space remains blank. I don't want to keep its space blank. That space should disappear and frame should get resized. Is there any way that I can achieve this? when user again clicks on the link(change no of textboxes I am again displaying 4th textbox.

code:

```
m_ComputerNameText1 = new wxTextCtrl(m_panel, wxID_ANY, "computerName", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(250, wxDefaultSize.GetHeight()));
m_ComputerNameText2 = new wxTextCtrl(m_panel, wxID_ANY, "computerName1", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(250, wxDefaultSize.GetHeight()));
m_ComputerNameText3 = new wxTextCtrl(m_panel, wxID_ANY, "computerName3", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(250, wxDefaultSize.GetHeight()));
m_ComputerNameText4 = new wxTextCtrl(m_panel, wxID_ANY, "computerName4", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(250, wxDefaultSize.GetHeight()));
m_hyperLinkOption = new wxHyperlinkCtrl(m_panel, wxID_ANY, "Change no of textboxes", wxT(""), wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(135, wxDefaultSize.GetHeight()));

m_userPassSizer->Add(m_ComputerNameText1, 0, wxALIGN_LEFT | wxALL, 0);
m_userPassSizer->Add(m_ComputerNameText2, 0, wxALIGN_LEFT | wxALL, 0);
m_userPassSizer->Add(m_ComputerNameText3, 0, wxALIGN_LEFT | wxALL, 0);
m_userPassSizer->Add(m_ComputerNameText4, 0, wxALIGN_LEFT | wxALL, 0);
m_userPassSizer->Add(m_hyperLinkOption , 0, wxALIGN_LEFT | wxALL, 0);
```

Following function executes when hyperlink is clicked.

```
void OnAuthCodeOptionLinkClicked(wxHyperlinkEvent& event)
{
    if (!m_hyperlinkOptionSelected)
    {
    m_hyperlinkOptionSelected= true;
    m_ComputerNameText4->Hide();
    m_hyperLinkOption->SetLabel("Go back");
}
else
{
    m_hyperlinkOptionSelected= false;
    m_ComputerNameText4->Show();
    m_hyperLinkOption->SetLabel("change no of textboxes");
}
```

}

in this way I have to hide and show 4th textbox. After hiding some blank space remains. How can I avaoid that blank space and take link in the place of 4th textbox ?

Comment: I don't see you call Layout() in you constructor to lay out your control as appropriate. Did you just omit it when you posted here?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need to dynamically update the size of a control, I always call `Layout()` and `Refresh()`.

You can find more info about Layout here:
http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_window.html#a1b143c3e72bd0af533b76db4830a6113
As well as some good info on window sizing in general here:
http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/overview_windowsizing.html

Calling Layout assumes that your class where you construct and manage your textboxes, etc. is a wxWindow derived control itself (like a panel, frame, whatever).  If not, like you are making the changes on a view-model, you will need to call Layout and Refresh on the owning window:

```
void UpdateView()
{
    view->Layout();
    view->Refresh();
}
```

You may need to play around with your sizers, minimum size of windows, etc. to get the exact behavior you want.

Comment: "Whenever I need to dynamically update the size of a control, I always call Layout() and Refresh()" - is that just [cargo cult](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)ing or do you actually have a *reason/explanation* of why you do that?

Comment: It means there is often more than one way to accomplish a given task and this is the way I choose to do it.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, there is a reason/explanation. Calling Layout() on the topmost window, results in recalculating positions/sizes of all controls that are on that window recursively. And I don't think there is another way of doing it. Refresh() call may not be needed, but I'm not sure.